# Does USB 2.0 provide interrupts for connected devices?

Tags: architecture

I know every USB device has a control pipe, however I read somewhere that USB doesn't allow it to trigger an interrupt WHILE the device is connected. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for the OS to verify the status of the device periodically? Or is that the same thing?

Comment: USB 2.0 doesn't say anything about whether the CPU interrupts anything or not.

Comment: No idea - try [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) - it's more infrastructure related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you care about an interrupt on CPU level, but there are interrupts in the USB protocol.

USB 2.0 defined 4 types of transfer methods:

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Overview):

> - isochronous transfers: at some guaranteed data rate (often, but not
>     necessarily, as fast as possible) but
>     with possible data loss (e.g. realtime
>     audio or video).
> - **interrupt transfers:** devices that need guaranteed quick responses
>     (bounded latency) (e.g. pointing
>     devices and keyboards).
> - bulk transfers: large sporadic transfers using all remaining
>     available bandwidth, but with no
>     guarantees on bandwidth or latency
>     (e.g. file transfers).
> - control transfers: typically used for short, simple commands to the
>     device, and a status response, used,
>     for example, by the bus control pipe
>     number 0.

AFAIK they aren't real interrupts though, polling will actually be done, but on the software side it should feel like an interrupt.